# Magento 1.9 layout update order/inheritance

Tags: xml, magento, layout, magento-1.9

Did Magento change something with how the layout updates are merged in 1.9?  I recently started working with 1.9.1.0 and I noticed that one of the blocks on the right side bar was duplicated.  This block is added by a 3rd party module that stores its theme files in default/default.  I had added code in my local.xml to unset the child and then re-add it so it appears at the bottom of the column.  This used to work in 1.5.0.1 but does not work in 1.9.1.0.  Instead, I was forced to remove the block completely using `<remove name=...>` and then add it back in using a different name.  It's a work-around I'm ok with, but is this supposed to be happening?

#### 3rd party module's layout update:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="adjreminder/review" name="right.adjreminder" after="cart_sidebar" template="adjreminder/review.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

#### My local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>right.adjreminder</name>
        </action>
        ...
        <block type="adjreminder/review" name="right.adjreminder" after="cart_sidebar" template="adjreminder/review.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This did not move the block but instead created a second copy.  The `unsetChild` wasn't doing anything.  The only way to fix it was for me to put this in my local.xml:

```
<default>
    <remove name="right.adjreminder" />

    <reference name="right">
        <block type="adjreminder/review" name="right.adjreminder" after="cart_sidebar" template="adjreminder/review.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: How did you re-add it?  Could you show some code?  Did you use action method insert, append, or create an entirely new block reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<remove>` directive does not remove blocks, but instead sets a flag to ignore block rendering of itself and all of it's children.  If you wish to relocate a block, you need to use the `<action>` directive with the method of `insert` or `append`.

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>right.adjreminder</name>
    </action>

    <action method="insert">
        <name>right.adjreminder</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

These action methods will use the current block instance instead of creating a new block instance.  The action method `insert` will place it at the top of the list of children, while `append` will place it at the bottom.

Comment: Interesting.  Are "insert" and "append" new(er) directives?  I wasn't aware of those in 1.5.  In 1.5, if you unset a child and then add it back in via a "<block>" tag it would only add one copy.  Now it seems to work differently.  Is this a bug or new functionality?  I'll try append and see what happens.

Comment: It's been around since the beginning.  The methods are in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.  You can see them [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php) in Magento 1.1

Comment: Guess I missed those.  Regardless, I just tried this method and it didn't work.  I don't believe I have any customizations in place that would be altering this functionality or breaking the "unsetChild" method.  I'll have to test it some time on a clean install.  For now I'm going to keep the "remove" combined with creating the block again using a different name.

Comment: After some additional testing and other issues that came up, I re-visited this solution and it seems to work.  I'm pretty sure Magento 1.5 handled this differently, but that's water under the bridge at this point.  Thanks for your help, @ryan-street